# Prove that sequence diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having some trouble proving that this sequence diverges. Can anyone suggest how to approach & proceed?

$a_n = \frac{n!}{2^n}$

Comment: consider $a_n = \frac12 \frac22 \frac 32 \frac 42 \ldots \frac{n}2$; or $a_{2n} = \frac12 \frac22 \frac 32 \frac 42 \ldots \frac{2n}2$; or the fact that $a_{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{2} a_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n! \geq n\cdot 2^{n-2}$    (at least for large $n$)

Thus
$$ a_n = \frac{n!}{2^n} \geq \frac{n2^{n-2}}{2^n} = n\cdot\frac{1}{4} \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$$

Which means $a_n$ tends to $\infty$

---

Where $n! \geq n\cdot 2^{n-2}$ holds because

$$n! = n\cdot\underbrace{\underbrace{(n-1)}_{\geq2}\cdot\underbrace{(n-2)}_{\geq2}\dots\cdot\underbrace{3}_{\geq2}\cdot\underbrace{2}_{\geq2}}_{n-2 \text{ factors }}\cdot1$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand, but where does the first line come from?

Comment: I made an edit so you can see it

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a_n \geq 1$ for all n. Also, $a_{n+1}/a_n=(n+1)/2$. So it's clear that $a_n$ can't converge, as otherwise $a_{n+1}/a_n$ would have limit $1$ while $(n+1)/2$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$n!/2^n=(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{2}{2})(\frac{3}{2})\cdots (\frac{n}{2})$. Except for the first two factors, these are all at least $\frac{3}{2}$, so the product is at least $(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{2}{2})\cdot (\frac{3}{2})^{n-2}$ for $n>2$.